# Perplexity issues using text2vec

Tags: for-loop, text-mining, text2vec

I am ussing text2vec on 230k docs, as I always mention. I am trying to find the best topic number for my document term matrix by using perplexity. When I use it one by one it works perfectly fine, but when I try to use a loop to get it for a range from 2 to 25 it doesn't work and I can't tell why, could  someone please tell me what is wrong?

```
##Using perplexity for hold out set
t1 <- Sys.time()
perplex <- c()
for (i in 2:25){

  set.seed(17)

    lda_model <- LDA$new(n_topics = i)
    doc_topic_distr <- lda_model$fit_transform(x = dtm,  progressbar = F)

    perplex[i]  <- text2vec::perplexity(sample.dtm, topic_word_distribution = 
    lda_model$topic_word_distribution, doc_topic_distribution = new_doc_topic_distr) 
}
print(difftime(Sys.time(), t1, units = 'sec'))
```

```
INFO [2019-10-23 13:01:43] early stopping at 80 iteration
INFO [2019-10-23 13:01:45] early stopping at 20 iteration
INFO [2019-10-23 13:01:53] early stopping at 70 iteration
INFO [2019-10-23 13:01:55] early stopping at 20 iteration
Error in text2vec::perplexity(sample.dtm, topic_word_distribution = lda_model$topic_word_distribution,  : 
  nrow(topic_word_distribution) == ncol(doc_topic_distribution) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need to re-calculate `new_doc_topic_distr` inside the loop

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your patience.  I added everything all over again inside the loop and only took 9 minutes.

Comment: Accept answer please